# Check how often a BPL-Package is loaded

Tags: delphi, delphi-10-seattle

I am loading forms from different BPL-Packages like explained here:
http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/27178

However i don't show them modal.

So it can happen that the same package (and form) gets loaded twice - and sometimes that is needed.

When i now call `DoUnloadPackage` not only the one form gets unloaded (and therefore closed) but all loaded forms from this package.

So my question is if there is a way to check how often a specific package is loaded.

At the moment i am saving the package handles in a list.

- Whenever a package gets loaded i add its package handle.
- Whenever a package gets unloaded i remove its package handle.

When there is only one handle for a package i completly unload it.

Basically i modified `DoUnloadPackage` like this:

```
var loadedmodules: TList<HModule>;

procedure DoUnloadPackage(Module: HModule);
var
  i: Integer;
  M: TMemoryBasicInformation;
begin
  // remove the modules handle from the list 
  loadedmodules.Delete(loadedmodules.IndexOf(Module));

  // maybe there are still more forms loaded from the same package?
  if loadedmodules.IndexOf(Module) <> -1 then
  begin
    { Make sure there aren't any instances of any
      of the classes from Module instantiated, if
      so then free them.  (This assumes that the
      classes are owned by the application) }

    for i := Application.ComponentCount - 1 downto 0 do
    begin
      VirtualQuery(GetClass(Application.Components[i].ClassName), M, SizeOf(M));

      if (Module = 0) or (HMODULE(M.AllocationBase) = Module) then
        Application.Components[i].Free;
    end;
    UnRegisterModuleClasses(Module);
  end;

  // gets always called
  UnLoadPackage(Module);
end;
```

So maybe there is an internal counter or function that determines how often a package got loaded? Thanks.

Comment: A package can't be loaded twice. And since you're loading the forms you could simply keep count.